# How pass JSON object itself instead of passing the file directory using New-AzureRmDataFactoryLinkedService

Tags: json, powershell, azure, runbook

I need to use bellow command in Azure Runbooks:

```
New-AzureRmDataFactoryLinkedService $MyDataFactoryObject -File "PATH/TO/JSON/STRING/FILE"
```

I am wondering to know is it possible to pass JSON Object itself instead of passing the file path?
I mean something like this:

```
$StorageLinkedService_JSON_str = '{
    "name": "StorageName",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureStorage",
        "description": "",
        "typeProperties": {
            "connectionString": "connectionString"
        }
    }
}'

$StorageLinkedService_Obj = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $StorageLinkedService_JSON_str

# I need to know is it possible to use one of these lines?
# New-AzureRmDataFactoryLinkedService $MyDataFactoryObject -File $StorageLinkedService_JSON_str
# OR This:
# New-AzureRmDataFactoryLinkedService $MyDataFactoryObject -File $StorageLinkedService_Obj
```

Comment: According to the Microsoft documentation of [New-AzureRmDataFactoryLinkedService](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactories/new-azurermdatafactorylinkedservice?view=azurermps-4.4.0) the `-File` parameter expects the path to the json file. Nothing else. So no. None if this lines will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where the runbook is executed, a possibility might be to write your JSON data to a temporary file:

```
$jsonFilePath = 'C:\Windows\Temp\StorageLinkedService_JSON_str.json'
$StorageLinkedService_JSON_str | 
    Out-File -FilePath $jsonFilePath
New-AzureRmDataFactoryLinkedService $MyDataFactoryObject -File $jsonFilePath
```